# Creating Outlook Rules with Win32 - Cant set destination folder for CopyToFolder rule action

Tags: python, winapi, outlook, win32com

I am writting a piece of Python code that updates a rule in Outlook.

The rule has 3 conditions:

1. The sender's email contains a particular string
2. The email has an attachement
3. OnLocalMachine is true

The rule has only 1 action (which i can't get to work)

1. To copy (not move) the email to a predefined destination folder.

Here is the code:

```
#Update the rule in personal account
lst=[]
lst.append('test.com')

outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
targetfolder = outlook.Folders('personal@address.com').Folders('Inbox').Folders('Reports')

rules=outlook.Folders('personal@address.com').Store.GetRules()      
rule=rules.Create('Python Test',0) # 0 is the value for the parameter olRuleReceive


condition= rule.Conditions.SenderAddress
condition.Address=lst
condition.Enabled = True

condition2= rule.Conditions.HasAttachment
condition2.Enabled=True

condition3=rule.Conditions.OnLocalMachine
condition3.Enabled=True

#from here on it doesnt work
action1=rule.Actions.CopyToFolder
action1.Folder=targetfolder
action1.Enabled=True

# I have also found this online and tried it. Does not work
#action1.__MoveOrCopyRuleAction__com__set_Enabled(True) 
#action1.__MoveOrCopyRuleAction__com__set_Folder(targetfolder)


rules.Save()
```

I have been able to do it in VBA. It looks like this:

```
Set oCopyRuleAction = newrule.Actions.CopyToFolder
With oCopyRuleAction
    .Enabled = True
Set .Folder = targetFolder
End With
```

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* isn't a problem statement. Please read [ask].

Comment: Sorry, first question ever. Here is the error message:


---> 36 rules.Save()
     37 

P:\WinPython\WPy64-3500\python-3.6.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in Save(self, ShowProgress)

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'One or more rules cannot be saved because of invalid actions or conditions.', None, 0, -2147467259), None)

Comment: If you find it difficult to understand how Stack Overflow works, why did you decide that it was good idea to skip taking the [tour]?